# Trying to make custom control, need to notify when a change was made to the value

Tags: java, datepicker, javafx

I have a DatePicker, from the javafx import. However i need it to contain a Calendar property, this is why i made a custom control that extends DatePicker.

However every time the datepicker is changed it should call this property thats why i think i have to use the .notify method when an onAction event is performed. This throws an `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException` exception.

This is the code i am using for this custom control:

```
public class DatePickerControl extends DatePicker
{
    private ObjectProperty<Calendar> calendar;

    public DatePickerControl() {
        super();
        setValue(LocalDate.now());
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of calendar
     *
     * @return the value of calendar
     */
    public ObjectProperty<Calendar> calendarProperty() {        
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        System.out.println("test");
        calendar.set(getValue().getYear(), getValue().getMonthValue(), getValue().getDayOfMonth());
        return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(calendar);
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of calendar
     *
     * @param calendar new value of calendar
     */
    public void setCalendar(Calendar calendar) {
        this.calendar.set(calendar);
        LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now();
        ld.withYear(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        ld.withMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        ld.withDayOfMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));        
        setValue(ld);
    }

    public Calendar getCalendar() {
        return calendar.get();
    }
}
```

and where i call the .notify():

```
dpAgendaRange.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
       t.notify();
    }
});
```

I am new to JavaFX so my apologies if the code is not very structural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `notify()` doesn't do what you think it does. It is part of the low-level concurrency API and is concerned with waking up threads that are in a wait() blocking status. You can read up on this [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) though it's not really to do with what you are trying to do.

I think what you are looking to do is to have an `ObjectProperty<Calendar>` which always matches the date value in your `DatePicker`'s `valueProperty`.

To do this, just define the `ObjectProperty<Calendar>` in the usual way: i.e. create it just once, and have a `setCalendar(...)` method that sets its value, a `getCalendar()` method that gets its value, and a `calendarProperty()` method that returns the Property itself.

To maintain the binding between the `ObjectProperty<Calendar>` and the `valueProperty` of the `DatePicker`, just register a listener with each one and update the other when either one changes.

(Also, note that the numbering of months is different between LocalDate and Calendar.)

So something like this:

```
public class DatePickerControl extends DatePicker {
    private ObjectProperty<Calendar> calendar;

    private DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE ;
    private Format calendarFormatter = DateFormat.getDateInstance();

    public DatePickerControl() {
        super();
        setValue(LocalDate.now());
        calendar = new SimpleObjectProperty<Calendar>(Calendar.getInstance());

        calendar.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println("calendar changed from "+calendarFormatter.format(oldValue.getTime())+" to "+calendarFormatter.format(newValue.getTime()));
            LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now()
                .withYear(newValue.get(Calendar.YEAR))
                .withMonth(newValue.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)
                .withDayOfMonth(newValue.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            setValue(localDate);
        });

        valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println("Value changed from "+dateFormatter.format(oldValue)+" to "+dateFormatter.format(newValue));
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(getValue().getYear(), getValue().getMonthValue()-1, getValue().getDayOfMonth());
            calendar.set(cal);
        });
    }


    public ObjectProperty<Calendar> calendarProperty() {        
        return calendar;
    }

    public void setCalendar(Calendar calendar) {
        this.calendar.set(calendar);
    }

    public Calendar getCalendar() {
        return calendar.get();
    }
}
```

A simple test:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            VBox root = new VBox();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);

            DatePickerControl datePicker = new DatePickerControl();
            Label label = new Label();
            final DateFormat calFormatter = DateFormat.getDateInstance() ;
            datePicker.calendarProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> label.setText(calFormatter.format(newValue.getTime())));
            root.getChildren().addAll(datePicker, label);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```